# How to copy artifacts from upstream project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two upstream projects(Pro1, Pro2). Both of the upstream projects archive artifacts. I want to create one downstream projects to copy artifacts from the upstream project who trigger the downstream project.

For example, if the downstream is triggered by `Pro1`, then it will copy the artifacts from `Pro1` not `Pro2`. In Jenkins, I can configure a project to copy artifacts from other projects but I have to specify the other project name. How can I specify a runtime project name in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of implementation approach for your required scenario,

Pass Upstream Job name to Downstream Job as input parameter.

Use [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to check which Job triggered the downstream using the Job name input parameter. By using this add conditional statement to check and copy the artifacts from respective Job.

Comment: In the conditional buildstep plugin, which one should I select for `Run?`? There are many of them like `Boolean Conditional, Build Cause, File Exists` etc. Which one can be used to read build parameter?

Comment: Strings match
Run if the two strings are the same

Comment: So you mean I should check whether `$PROJECT_NAME` is equal to `Pro1`?

Comment: Yes, you have to place the condition like that.