# How to Pass Files to downstream Job in Jenkins

Tags: file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pass a zip file of a build down to another job that runs the end to end tests. It would usually use the build artifacts from the main job, but I want to add the end to end tests as part of the build pipeline. I tried using the file parameter in Jenkins but the file never showed up and I believe there's some outstanding issues preventing it from working. Is there a way I can pass the files to a downstream job via stashing/file parameter. or could do I have to do something like create a downstream job that does the build and then take the artifacts and use it in a master job that also runs the end to end tests too?

This is how I tried the file parameter

```
parameters {
    file name:"buildFiles.zip", description: 'Zip file containing Build Files'
}
```

Note: I am using a Jenkinsfile for the jobs.

UPDATE: The way I ended up solving the issue was to push the finished builds to a proget universal package repo and then let the downstream job pull from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins [COPY ARTIFACT PLUGIN](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) helps copy artifacts from specific projects to the project you want. The link given has details how it can be done. This SO thread [Build selector for Copy Artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463906/10363259) also explains the same on how it is done.

Comment: Will it work if the job that the artifacts are coming from is not finished running? the files would be coming from a still-running upstream job.

Comment: Yes you can. I'm using my.mobile to update the comment, so couldn't add more info. In your case I'd do the same as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45301462

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes you have the file in the current job's workspace.

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Pass file type param to build job') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def propertiesFilePath = "${env.WORKSPACE}/sample.properties"
                    build job: 'other-project',
                            parameters: [[$class: "FileParameterValue", name: "propertiesFile", file: new FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl(new File(propertiesFilePath))]]

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the name of the downstream/child job is 'other-project' and the name of the file type parameter in this downstream/child job is 'propertiesFile'. The type FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl is defined in the class FileParameterValue and is internally used in jenkins to handle FileItem, also adding serialization support to the same.

Comment: this workaround doesn't work